# How to change color of drawable ImageView android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

i have a `vector` icon in my `drawable` package `ic_vector_point_image`:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:viewportWidth="3"
    android:viewportHeight="3">
  <path
      android:pathData="M1.5,1.5m-1.5,0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,3 0a1.5,1.5 0,1 1,-3 0"
      android:fillColor="#4C55E4"/> --- blue color
</vector>
```

Then i use this `vector` icon with my `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/point"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3.7dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_typing_indicator_point"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/typing_text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

I need to set the `argb` color for this `drawable` like this:
`imageView.setColor(Color.argb())`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tint of the image view like this:

`imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));` // White

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setImageTintList()`  method for that.

In Kotlin:

```
imageView.imageTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red))
```